# Maintain image aspect ratio and use width percentage

Tags: html, css

Using css i gave 2 divs a background image (both these divs are 50% width), and placed those divs inside a container (100% width)

```
//css
.banner_container { width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; }
.banner_small { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); width: 50%; height: 100%; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; float: left; }
```

This fiddle contains the code http://jsfiddle.net/1nqbu0mw/

My problem is, when i give them a fixed height (e.g. 200px) the images are squished together. 
When i give it height: auto; the images become smaller whenever i resize the screen or zoom in/out.
I've also tried using the following code;

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 64em)" src="high-res.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" src="med-res.jpg">
   <source src="low-res.jpg">
   <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="This picture loads on non-supporting browsers.">
   <p>Accessible text.</p>
</picture>
```

Unfortunately i couldnt get this to work either.

My question is, how can i make sure they stay the correct width and height, without the sides being trimmed off and keep the images centered?

For an example of what i would like see the following website and scroll down a bit. (http://weareadaptable.com/)

Is there a way to do this in just css or does this require jquery/js?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/1nqbu0mw/

```
<div class="banner_container">
<div class="banner_small"></div>
<div class="banner_small"></div>
```

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.banner_container { width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; }
.banner_small { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); width: 50%; height: 100%; background-position: top center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto; float: left; }
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it still scales the image weirdly unfortunately, so not quite what i'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "weirdly"? Do the images need to have a minimum height? What about http://jsfiddle.net/0nq887jo/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an responsive website, I suggests using a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), it already solves a lot of issues like yours. Also, on their website there are many examples to help you get strarted.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken another look at it, and it turns out I wasn't using images in the same aspect ratio, pretty silly.

I've now made sure all my images are in the same aspect ratio, so everything works fine now!